# Getting specific user input and argument count in function in c using scanf or fgets?

Tags: c, fgets, scanf

I am trying to get a user input into a function, using `scanf` or `fgets`.

I am writing C.

The user must input 2 (positive) integers. The difference between this two must be 1. 
I have to check if in fact only 2 parameters were given.

The function should return the smaller one of the given integers, if:

- given argument count == 2
- the difference is in fact 1

The function should return -1 if:

- argument count != 2
- the difference is > 1

The function should return -2 if:

- both given arguments have the same value

I have no problem comparing the integers and returning the right value, my problem is with the input.
So far I´ve tried this approaches:

1.)

```
int getInput(){
  int user_input_nod_1;
  int user_input_nod_2;
  scanf("%d %d",&user_input_nod_1,&user_input_nod_2)
  (...)
}
```

The problem here is that I have no way of knowing if the user has entered more than 2 integers.

2.)

```
int getInput(){
  int user_input_nod_1;
  int user_input_nod_2;
  char user_input_over;
  scanf("%d %d",&user_input_nod_1,&user_input_nod_2)
  scanf("%c",&user_input_over)
  if(user_input_over != '\0'){
     return -1;
  }
  (...)
}
```

Here the program returns -1 if more that two parameters are given, and works perfectly when given two parameters, but if given only one `scanf` waits till infinity for the second input (even after pressing enter). The user **does not** know how to end a stream (cmd+d,...)

3.)

```
int getInput(){    
  char input_nods[10];

  if(fgets(input_nods, 10, stdin) != NULL)
  {
     puts(input_nods);
  }

  char input_c1;
  char input_c2;
  char input_nod_over;

  sscanf(input_nods,"%c %c %c",&input_c1, &input_c2, &input_nod_over);

  char *nod_check_1, *nod_check_2;
  int input_nod_1 = strtol(&input_c1, &nod_check_1, 10);
  int input_nod_2 = strtol(&input_c2, &nod_check_2, 10);

  if (input_nod_over != '\0' || input_nods[2] == ' ' || input_nods[2] == '\0')
  {
      return -1;
  }
}
```

This works perfectly when given integers in the range 0-9. As soon as the input has two digits `sscanf` gets messed up with the whitespace that `fgets` saved in input_nodes[].

Is there a way that I could achieve what I´m looking for?
Thanks.

Comment: Read the documentation of `scanf`.

Comment: I was gonna write something sarcastic, but then I found what I was looking for buried deep inside some website on scanf. Thanks ^^

Comment: Comments by higher-rep users are most times worth thinking about. Regardless if they are brief or not :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved it now using this loop:

```
int user_input_nod_1;
int user_input_nod_2;

char buf[BUFSIZ], junk[BUFSIZ];

fprintf( stderr, "> " );              
while ( fgets( buf, sizeof(buf), stdin ) != NULL )
{
    if ( sscanf( buf, "%i%i%[^\n]", &user_input_nod_1, &user_input_nod_2, junk ) == 2 )
        break;
    fprintf( stderr, "[ERR] \n" );
    fprintf( stderr, "> " );
}
```

(using ">  " as some kind of cursor...)

Answer (score 0):

In the third way, you could use `input_nod_1` and `input_nod_2`, and do not use the `sscanf` function at all.

In the first use of `strtol`, you have to check that `nod_check_1` is blank (or a space if you want to be more specific), and in the second use you have to check that `nod_check_2` is `NULL`.

However, I would use `long` as `strtol` result (in order to avoid long->int casting overflow), and check for `errno` in case that `strtol` returns 0.